# UNIX shell I/O redirection

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to implement a LINUX shell in C but when I am trying to run a command like this : `sort -u < in.txt > out.txt` it says : `sort: cannot read: '<': No such file or directory` . I also tried other commands like `ls -l > out.txt` etc but it keep telling me the same thing. Here is my code :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


#define LENGTH 1024

int main(){
char line[LENGTH];
char* argv[100];
char* path= "/bin/";
char fullPath[30];
int option;
char* inputFile;
char* outputFile;   

while(1){

    printf("mysh3>");

    if(!fgets(line,LENGTH,stdin)){
        break;
    }

    size_t length = strlen(line);
    if(line[length-1]=='\n')
        line[length-1] = '\0';

}

char* token; 
token = strtok(line," ");
int i = 0;
while(token!=NULL){
    argv[i]=token;
    token = strtok(NULL," ");
    i++;
}

if(argv[1]==">"){
    option=1;
    outputFile=argv[2];
}
else if(argv[2]==">"){
    option = 1;
    outputFile=argv[3];
}
else if(argv[1]=="<" && argv[3]==">"){
    option=2;
    inputFile=argv[2];
    outputFile=argv[4];
}
else if(argv[2]=="<" && argv[4]==">"){
    option=2;
    inputFile=argv[3];
    outputFile=argv[5];
}
else if(argv[1]=="<" && argv[3]==">>"){
    option=3;
    inputFile=argv[2];
    outputFile=argv[4];
}
else if(argv[2]=="<" && argv[4]==">>"){
    option=3;
    inputFile=argv[3];
    outputFile=argv[5];
}


argv[i]=NULL;

strcpy(fullPath, path);
strcat(fullPath, argv[0]);

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(fullPath); i++){  
    if(fullPath[i]=='\n'){
        fullPath[i]='\0';
    }
}

int ret=forkEx2(argv,inputFile,outputFile,fullPath,option);
if(ret==-1) {
    return -1;
}

int forkEx2(char* argv[],char* inputFile,char* outputFile,char 
fullPath[],int option){
int fd;
pid_t pid,waitPid;
pid = fork();
if(pid<0){
    perror("ERROR: Fork failed.\n");
    return -1;
}
else if(pid==0){
    if(option==1){
        fd=open(outputFile,O_CREAT | O_TRUNC |  O_WRONLY, 0600);  //if the file does not exist the system create it. Clear all data from the file. Open the file for write only.Store its file descriptor in fd

        dup2(fd,STDOUT_FILENO);  //replace the standar out with the file
        close(fd);
    }
    else if(option==2){
        fd=open(inputFile,O_RDONLY,0600);  //open the file for read only

        dup2(fd,STDIN_FILENO);  //replace the standar in with the file
        close(fd);

        fd=open(outputFile,O_CREAT | O_TRUNC |  O_WRONLY, 0600);  //if the file does not exist the system create it. Clear all data from the file. Open the file for write only

        dup2(fd,STDOUT_FILENO);  //replace the standar out with the file
        close(fd);
    }
    else if(option==3){
        fd=open(inputFile,O_RDONLY,0600);  //open the file for read only

        dup2(fd,STDIN_FILENO);  //replace the standar in with the file
        close(fd);

        fd=open(outputFile, O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, 0600);  //append at the end of the file. Open the file for write only

        dup2(fd,STDOUT_FILENO);  //replace the standar out with the file
        close(fd);
    }

    execvp(fullPath,argv);
    perror("ERROR: Child should never arrive here.\n");

}

else{
    waitPid = wait(&waitPid);
    if (waitPid == -1) {
        perror("ERROR: Waitpid failed.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Parent: Finished pid %d.\n", waitPid);
}
}                   

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you check what you're passing to `exec` ? I bet the redirect symbols are still there.

Comment: oh right thanks for the help !

Comment: Note that in POSIX shells, you can write `ls>output` or even `>output ls`.  And you can use `tr >output 'A-Z' <input 'a-z'`. That is, the redirection symbols do not have to be separate from the file name, and can occur in any order, and can even precede the command name.  Your existing code, therefore, is not equivalent to this level of complexity.  You will need to consider some of these issues in due course, even if it isn't necessary immediately.

Answer (score 2):

let's take that case (it's the same in all cases):

```
else if(argv[2]=="<" && argv[4]==">"){
    option=2;
    inputFile=argv[3];
    outputFile=argv[5];
}
```

First, you're comparing strings using `==`: that doesn't work. You have to use `strcmp` or you're comparing the pointers.

Then, you're extracting input file & output file all right, but you forget to remove the redirection arguments from `argv`. You have to filter them out (by shifting the rest of the argument array each time you encounter one redirection argument)

Aside: you should initialize your `argv` array or you may meet undefined behaviour if there are not enough arguments.